# Update Twitter status using PHP Form

Tags: php, twitter, curl

I have the following code, but it doesn't update my status (the username and password has been removed for this snippet) and it throws the error eeek. Any ideas why it's not working?

EDIT:

Apparently Twitter NEEDS OAuth instead now. I have been following this tutorial here: http://ditio.net/2010/06/07/twitter-php-oauth-update-status/

I have registered my App and copied both the Library and Tokens over.

BUT I'm not sure how to get this working with my current code, ie. what needs changing/adding/removing.

My Updated code:

```
<?php

    function postToTwitter($username,$password,$message)
    {

        require_once 'TwitterOAuth.php';

        define("CONSUMER_KEY", "???");
        define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "???");
        define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "???");
        define("OAUTH_SECRET", "???");

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
        $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

        $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => date(DATE_RFC822)));

        // GET the API url via web authentication
        // add 'status' param to send a message to Twitter

        $host = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml?status=".urlencode(stripslashes(urldecode($message)));

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Go for it!!!
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        // Look at the returned header
        $resultArray = curl_getinfo($ch);

        // close curl
        curl_close($ch);

        //echo "http code: ".$resultArray['http_code']."<br />";

        if($resultArray['http_code'] == "200"){
            echo "<br />OK! posted to http://twitter.com/".$username."/<br />";
        } else {
            echo "eek! yegads! error posting to Twitter";
        }

        // debug the result
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($resultArray);
        // echo "</pre><hr>";

        // $sResult = htmlentities($result);
        // $sResult = str_replace("&gt;&lt;","&gt;<br />&lt;",$sResult);

        // echo "<pre>";
        // print $sResult;
        // echo "</pre>";

    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $textmessage = $_POST['message'];
        postToTwitter("whiningwall","u0558234",$textmessage);
    }

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="post" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

            <fieldset>

                <label for="textArea">What's on your mind?</label>
                <textarea id="textArea" name="message" maxlength="140"></textarea>

                <div class="submit">
                    <span class="charsRemaining"></span>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Share" />
                </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maxlength.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#textArea').focus();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If someone would be able to help with the updated OAuth code that'd be awesome. Thank you

Comment: Any updates? Would like to get this work asap. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that CURLOPT_USERPWD is for Apache's basic authentication, which Twitter does not use. I don't know much about the Twitter API but I think you'll be better off using OAuth to tell Twitter who you are.

Edit to add: There's GPL twitter library at http://code.google.com/p/php-twitter/ that you might try looking at (or even using).

Comment: Updated my question. Would you be able to help me get the OAuth working with my code.